# Does Qt leak memory?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gcc, address-sanitizer

If I compile this Qt "hello world":

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>


int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  QApplication a( argc, argv );

  QPushButton hello( "Hello world!" );
  hello.resize( 100, 30 );

  hello.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

on Debian Stable (using system Qt libraries) with GCC 12.2 (installed from source)

```
$ g++ -fsanitize=address hello.cpp -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -fPIC
```

This leads to leaks being detected, when I close the application:

```
$ ./a.out 

=================================================================
==3563910==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 6656 byte(s) in 26 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fea3b4801af in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../gcc-12.2.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:69
    #1 0x7fea3693c704  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1+0x20704)

Indirect leak of 1600 byte(s) in 50 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fea3b47fb97 in __interceptor_calloc ../../../../gcc-12.2.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:77
    #1 0x7fea3693cd48  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1+0x20d48)

Indirect leak of 519 byte(s) in 50 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fea3b437f3b in __interceptor_strdup ../../../../gcc-12.2.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cpp:439
    #1 0x7fea3693bfa4 in FcValueSave (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1+0x1ffa4)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 8775 byte(s) leaked in 126 allocation(s).
```

Is this a false positive?

Comment: Can be due to QT's special memory management system. Parent deletes pending children upon destruction. Therefore, QT `new`ed widgets are never to be explicitly `delete`d. But this is just a hunch.

Comment: Hard to tell, the leaks seem to be about libfontconfig not Qt. <https://github.com/behdad/fontconfig/blob/master/README> talks quite lot about "fixing leaks".

Comment: Note that call stack from this leak report do not contain `main` function. This some means statically linked dynamic library has an issue `libfontconfig.so`.  Note other peapol see same issue without using Qt: https://github.com/Raymo111/i3lock-color/issues/88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I underestand that in QtCreator we can add `CONFIG += sanitizer sanitize_address` in the `.pro` File to enable **sanitizer** and I test in a simple template project with one MainWindow. I test it in Qt 5.15.2 and I saw a memory leaks error.

[image]

But as I test it in `Qt_6_2_3` it works correctly.
So I think this relates to Qt 5 version and they fixed it in Qt 6.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Qt 5.15.8 at least.